# What are the assumptions that should be made for the determination of the unknown integration constants in this system of dual integral equations?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions, integral-equations, integral-transforms

Consider the following dual integral equations (which arise in some elasticity situations)
$$
\int_0^\infty q^3 f(q) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d}q = g(r)\, , \quad\quad (0<r<R) \, , \\
\int_0^\infty f(q) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d}q = 0 \, , \quad\quad (r>R) \, ,
$$
wherein $g(r)$ is a known function.

For its solution, I put
$$
 f (q) = \int_0^R \chi(t) \sin (qt) \, \mathrm{d} t \, , 
$$
which clearly satisfies the equation for $r>R$ owing to the identity
$$
\int_0^\infty J_0 (qr) \sin(qt) \, \mathrm{d} q = \frac{H(t-r)}{(t^2-r^2)^{1/2}} \, ,
$$
with $H$ being the Heaviside step function.
Substituting this solution form into the equation for $0<r<R$ and integrating successively by parts, we obtain
$$
 \int_0^R \chi(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \int_0^\infty q^3 J_0 (qr) \sin (qt) \, \mathrm{d} q = \\\int_0^\infty J_0(qr) \, \mathrm{d} q \bigg( \left(\chi''(R)-q^2 \chi(R)\right) \cos(qR) + q \chi'(R) \sin(qR) \\-\chi''(0) + q^2 \chi(0) - \int_0^R \chi'''(t) \cos(qt) \, \mathrm{d} t \bigg) \, .
$$

By making use of 
$$
\int_0^\infty J_0 (qr) \cos(qt) \, \mathrm{d} q = \frac{H(r-t)}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}} \, ,
$$
an under some assumptions, we can write
$$
-\int_0^r \frac{\chi'''(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}} = g(r) \, , \quad\quad (0<r<R) \, .
$$

Multiplying both members by $r/(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}$, integrating with respect to $r$ between 0 and $s$ and interchanging the integration order we obtain the following
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2} \chi''(s) = \int_0^s \frac{r g(r) \, \mathrm{d}r}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}}=: h(s) \, , \quad\quad (0<s<R) \, , 
$$
upon using the result
$$
 \int_t^s \frac{r\, \mathrm{d} r}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2} (r^2-t^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \, .
$$

Finally, by integrating the equation giving $\chi''(s)$ twice we obtain the solution up to 2 unknown integration constants.
My question is what are the assumptions that should be made for the determination of the unknown integration constants, notably in after the integration by part?

Your help and hints are very appreciated.

Thanks

Federiko

Comment: The second condition $\int_0^\infty f(q) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d}q = 0$ suggests the use of Hankel transform, but I have some difficulty solving it. But there are relative simple solutions, if the integrand for the first one is $q^2 f(q) J_0 (qr)$ or the integrand for the second one is $q f(q) J_0 (qr)$.

Comment: @yhhuang OK thanks. I think that the resolution procedure described above is commonly used to solve such problems. Actually may question is: Under the assumptions $\chi(0)=\chi''(0)=\chi(R)=\chi'(R)=0$, the passage to the simplified equation is legitimate. However, we get an additional restriction as we solve an equation of third order. I would guess $\chi(0)=\chi''(0)=0$ but one should take either $\chi(R)=0$ or $\chi'(R)=0$.

Comment: @yhhuang Note that the integral with $\chi''(R)$ vanishes owing to the equations with Heaviside function. If you could provide with some help it would be geat! Thanks.